# How i can authorizate on nike site with puppeteer?

Tags: javascript, node.js, puppeteer

I welcome everyone!
I decided to write a script that will simply log into the account and check the phone number on the account.
There was a problem with the login. I cannot log in, with this code I get the following error:

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer')

async function nike_login() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({
    devtools: true,
    args: ['--Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/91.0.4472.124 Safari/537.36'],
    defaultViewport: null,
    headless: false,
    slowMo: 50
  });

  const page = await browser.newPage();

  const url = 'https://www.nike.com/ru/launch';

  await page.goto(url);
}

nike_login();
```

Error: GENERIC "0 - POST request to https://unite.nike.com/login blocked"
[First misstake without '--disable-web-security'][1]
but with this flag:

```
'--disable-web-security'
```

i have next error
[with this flag][2]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/sw43t.png
[2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/H1cix.png

How i can authorizate? I tried a lot of things, but due to lack of knowledge I could have missed something, please help!

Answer (score 0):

Launch browser seem very simple but default `puppeteer.launch`  is actually not usefully. So I recommend you launch browser with another way like bellow:

1. Firstly, install some packages:

```
   "puppeteer": "^2.0.0",
   "puppeteer-core": "^2.0.0",
   "puppeteer-extra": "^2.1.3",
   "puppeteer-extra-plugin": "^3.0.4",
   "puppeteer-extra-plugin-anonymize-ua": "^2.1.4",
   "puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth": "^2.2.2",
```

2. Sample code:

```
const puppeteer = require("puppeteer-extra");
const pluginStealth = require("puppeteer-extra-plugin-stealth");
puppeteer.use(pluginStealth());

async function nike_login() {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({headless: 0});
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const url = 'https://www.nike.com/ru/launch';
  try {
    await page.goto(url, {timeout: 4000});
  } catch (err) {
    console.log('ignore this one because browser will loads many things that u do not need');
  }
//  continue your code
}

nike_login();
```

Comment: I still get an error at the entrance :(
GENERIC "0 - POST request to https://unite.nike.com/login blocked"